# Azure storage table: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request when searching in a column

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am getting this error while executing this query against Azure table storage:

```
var query = table.CreateQuery<DynamicTableEntity>()
                   .Where(d => d.PartitionKey == partitionId
                    && d.Properties["Content"].StringValue.Contains("Polly"))
                    ).AsTableQuery();
                    
                    var result = table.ExecuteQuery<DynamicTableEntity>(query);

                    foreach (var entity in result)
                        {
                         //Do stuff             
                        }
```

The error happens when executing this line:

```
foreach (var entity in result)
```

Now, the error and stacktrace are not very useful, but I was able to determine that the error is caused by the inclusion of this condition:

```
d.Properties["Content"].StringValue.Contains("Polly")
```

Remove this line and the problem disappear.

There is some sort of limitation about the usage of methods like "Contains" in a TableQuery?
If so there is any workaround, so that I can filter the rows that contain a given string in the field "Content"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is some sort of limitation about the usage of methods like
> "Contains" in a TableQuery?

This is correct. Azure Table Storage has support for limited number of LINQ operators and `Contains` is not one of them. For the list of support LINQ operators please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-operators-supported-for-the-table-service.

Comment: I thought that may be the case. So there is any workaround, way to achieve the same result? The only one I can think about is doing the table query without that filter, convert to result to a list, and then do a linq filter with the entities loaded in memory. But The problem is that this way seems a very inefficient way to perform the query, since the result is not filtered at database level, and potentially a lot of data will be loaded in memory.

Comment: Client side filtering (like you mentioned) is the only way to accomplish this.